# Selecting font for a specific section with options

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

I can use `\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}` to change the font of the entire document.
But I only want this to be done for a certain section.
What command should be used for this?

Comment: You can change the font family inside a group: `\begingroup
\fontfamily{mdbch}\selectfont this text is typeset in Charter 
\endgroup`. Note that this does not affect the argument of commands like `\section{...}`

Comment: @Ivan If you do this, I’d recommend you define a command such as `\charterfont` in the preamble. You’ll thank yourself when you need to change the command to switch to Charter someday.